# Flask: Flash function ignoring the 'category' argument

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flash-message

So I write the controller:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('Hello world!', 'success')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

then in my template I output the flash messages like this:

```
{%- with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) -%}
{%- if messages -%}
    <ul class="flashes unstyled">
    {%- for category, message in messages -%}
        <li class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            {{ message }}
        </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
    </ul>
{%- endif -%}
{%- endwith %}
```

But the issue is that I ALWAYS get just 'message' category so `<li>` goes with classes `'alert alert-message'`.
I read the docs and as to me I did everything right, but `'flash'` function ignoring the second argument and always uses the default value `'message'` (instead of given by me 'success').

I wonder if anyone had that issue and know how to handle it?

Comment: What version of flask are you using? It seems to be fine for me in 0.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:  Based on other comments and testing the kwarg is unnecessary.

Based on the docs at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#message-flashing it appears you need to use this format. `flash(message, category='message')`

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('Hello world!', category='success')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: You don't need to provide a kwarg to it. I use it in the form `flash('message', 'category')` and it works fine.

Comment: yep, you don't have to pass key=value pair (though you can).
And I tried that already... no results :(

Comment: @Joe  You are quite right.  I just tested it as well in Flask 0.10.1 and it is working properly.

Comment: Don't know what happend but with `category='success'` it worked!
Hmmm... strange... I'm sure I've tryied that way and it didn't help then. Well, the issue is solved so thank you!

Answer (score 5):

When you call `get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True)`, it return a list of tuples in the form `(category, message)`.

So now you can use `flash()` like this:

```
flash('some message', 'success') # `category=` is needn't
```

In html, you can just loop the message in the call:

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ message[0] }}">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    {{ message[1] }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```